# Why does my input (word) auto-update in this recursive code?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to copy a recursive code I saw on youtube, but I don't understand why does it auto-update word ?
I feel that it doesn't make sense since I for example didn't write a line of code to assign a new value to word ?

I understand everything in those lines except the last "return word" part

```
def clearword(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
       return word
    if word[0]== word[1]:
       return clearword(word[1:])
    return word
```

i called like like so to test it:

```
print(cleanword("WWWoooorrrldd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Iteration by iteration:

- 1st

word="WWWoooorrrldd"

enters the second `if` , recusively calls itself passing "WWoooorrrldd" (original word minus 'W')

- 2nd

word="WWoooorrrldd"

enters the second `if` again, recusively calls itself passing "Woooorrrldd" (original word minus  'WW'/1st iteration word minus 'W')

- 3rd

word="Woooorrrldd"

does not enter any `if` so it executes the last `return` hence concluding the total function call, returning the final word "Woooorrrldd" (no modification happen in this iteration)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 
In the 2nd iteration what made word ="WWoooorrrldd"? I understand the code itself and that I am passing word[1:] to the function again but why does it update word to become word[1:] ? (I mean I didn't use an assign operator for example) (sorry if that's a trivial question but I just want to understand what's happening in the background here)

Comment: The program doesn't update the original `word`. It calls the function `clearword` again with the value `word[1:]`. The value of this parameter will be known as `word` again, but that's a different `word`.